# How to filter a file by name file with different extension file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have some file with different extension.
Like this files

```
file123_A1.que
file456_B2.que
file123_00_A1.pro
file890_11_C2.pro
```

I want to copy the file by lastwritetime. But I don't want to copy the file if the file already has  .pro, even the file is the lastwritetime.
For the example, after sort the file by lastwritetime, the file that will be copied is `file123_A1.que` , but the that file name already has .pro by identify the 2 last file name `A1`. So in this case, I need to copy the other file.
My expectation I will not copy a file if the file has the same 2 last name with different extension file (ex: file123_A1.que and  file123_00_A1.pro the same 2 last file name. I will not copy this file file123_A1.que)

Anyone can give idea please. Thank you
I tried this

```
$Sel_JobFolder = "D:\601"
$JobFolder = @(Get-ChildItem "$Sel_JobFolder\*.que" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime)[0] | 
ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -path $_.FullName -destination .\ -force}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could take is:

- Get all files with [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) and sort by extension in a descending manner. So this means `.que` will come before `.pro` files. We can use [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7) here to sort a calculated property which extracts the extension with [`System.IO.Path.GetExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netframework-4.8), also ensuring we set `Descending = $true` to sort in descending order.
- Add files to a hash table, where the key is the last item from splitting the filename by `"_"` e.g. key will become `A1` from `file123_A1`. The idea here to replace `.que` files with `.pro` files if found.
- Iterate the hash table and copy the latest file. If a `.pro` file was found, then it will be copied instead of the `.que` file. If no `.pro` file was found, then we copy the `.que` file instead.

**Demo:**

```
$directory = "D:\601"

# sort files by extension in descending order
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = {[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_)}; Descending = $true}

# add files to hashtable. .que will be updated by .pro if found
$ht = @{}
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $key = $file.BaseName.Split("_")[-1]
    $ht[$key] = $file.FullName
}

# copy files here
foreach ($entry in $ht.GetEnumerator())
{
    Copy-Item -Path $entry.Value -Destination .\
}
```

Which will copy the following files to your current working directory `.\`:

```
D:\file456_B2.que
D:\file890_11_C2.pro
D:\file123_00_A1.pro
```

Here we can see `file123_A1.que` was excluded from the copying, because `file123_00_A1.pro` replaced it.